# In Microsoft.DirectX, Converting surface to bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, directx

I'm only using DirectX(DirectX for managed Code) in C# (not slimdx)

I want to get screenshot of which data type is bitmap.

So i want to know how can i convert surface to bitmap.

However i can't find any guide to do that.

Thank you for reading!

I also attach my source code so far

```
        PresentParameters present_params = new PresentParameters();
        present_params.Windowed = true;
        present_params.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard; 
        d = new Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, this,
         CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, present_params);

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Surface s =  CaptureScreen();

        ////////////////////////////
        ///need to do something/////
        ///////////////////////////

        s.Dispose();


    }
    public Surface CaptureScreen()
    {
        Surface s = d.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Scratch);
        d.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Managed DirectX has not been supported by microsoft for a long time ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a static helper method to do that:

```
Surface.ToFile(s, filename, ImageFileFormat.Png);
```